# iPhone: How to Share/Move Files from App Directories to Other Devices

Tags: iphone, ftp, bonjour, file-sharing, httpserver

I have an app which generates some files in the app directories

I need users to be able to access the files from another device/computer via file sharing over wifi, using a web browser, a ftp client or some similar method.

Can the iPhone act as a http server and ftp server by itself or do I need to do some programing to make the http server and ftp server by myself?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code examples for [Erica Sadun's rather excellent 3.0 edition of the iPhone Developer's Cookbook](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780321670168) are [downloadable at github](http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree). She has two chapters on various modes of networking including an example HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone has no built-in web or ftp server. So if you want this functionality to be part of your application then you will have to include one in your code.

Answer (score 0):

[CocoaHTTPServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) is an excellent library for this purpose, widely used also in iPhone apps. It has a good documentation and working example projects, even for iPhone.